# Write short description behind the document location (list of abbreviations in glossaries)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am using the glossaries package for the list of abbreviations. By default, a location list is displayed for each entry whih refers to the document location. It look´s like this: [image]

Now I would like to change the presentation of the location list. Instead of only list the page number I want to write a short text behind the number.

I know that is possible to change the text after the entry with this:

\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{...}

But how I can change the text after the page numbers? Is it possible at all?

Example:

```
\documentclass[
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
]{scrpage2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                 %% Deutsches Sprachpaket
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 %% Eingabezeichensatz UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    %% Kodierung für Umlaute
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}            %% Für Abkürzungsverzeichnis benötigt
\usepackage{lmodern}                        %% Moderne Version von Computer Modern
\usepackage{setspace}                       %% Zeileabstand anpassen

\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}  %% Deutsche Anführungs- und Ausführungsstriche

\usepackage{expdlist}                       %% Erweitert Description-Umgebung
\usepackage[                                %% Biblatex
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[
%xindy,
%nonumberlist,                              %% Keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym,                                    %% Ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen                  
toc]                                        %% Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
{glossaries}
%Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung bei Glossaries deaktivieren
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{aaa}

%Eigener Style für Glossaries
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{
\setglossarystyle{list}
%\setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{.2\hsize}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}
{\begin{description}[\setleftmargin{.2\hsize}]}{\end{description}}
}

%Alle Verzeichnisse mit einzeiligem Abstand
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}

\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\singlespacing}

%Eigener Style für Glossaries
\DeclareNameFormat {default}{%
\usebibmacro {name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
\usebibmacro {name:andothers}}

\newacronym[description={\glslink{CBIR}{Content Based Image Retrieval}}]{CBIR}{CBIR}{Content Based Image Retrieval}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

\gls{CBIR}

\clearpage

\deftranslation[to=German]{Acronyms}{Abkürzungs- und Akronymverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\protect\par\vspace{5ex}\noindent\textbf{Anmerkung: }Alle Einträge wurden den im Literatur- und Internetquellenverzeichnis aufgeführten Quellen entnommen.}
\printglossary[style=altlist, title=Glossar]

\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\protect\par\vspace{5ex}\noindent\textbf{Anmerkung: }Alle im Text verwendeten Abkürzungen sind im Abkürzungsverzeichnis aufgeführt. Bei der ersten Verwendung wurden diese ausgeschrieben und anschließend die zugehörige Abkürzung in Klammern angefügt. Bei einer erneuten Verwendung des Begriffs wurde nur die Abkürzung benutzt. Geläufige Abkürzungen und Firmennamen sind nicht aufgeführt.}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=mystyle]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can do this by defining a custom style, but it would help if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each (top-level) entry is displayed using `\glossentry`. This takes two arguments: the entry label and the location list. The `list` style redefines `\glossentry` as:

```
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
          \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
       \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}%
```

(The double hash `##` is because the redefinition occurs inside `\newglossarystyle`.) So to insert something after the location list you just need to modify this definition to include the inserted material after `##2`. For example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{expdlist}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{aaa}
\newcommand*{\postpagelist}{XXX}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
 \setglossarystyle{list}%
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{description}[\setleftmargin{.2\hsize}]}%
 {\end{description}}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
   \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
         \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
      \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\postpagelist}%
}

\newacronym{CBIR}{CBIR}{Content Based Image Retrieval}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

\gls{CBIR}

\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=mystyle]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of glossary]

If the inserted material is dependent on the entry, you can add the information to one of the user keys. For example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{expdlist}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{aaa}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
 \setglossarystyle{list}%
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{description}[\setleftmargin{.2\hsize}]}%
 {\end{description}}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
   \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
         \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
      \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\glsentryuseri{##1}}%
}

\newacronym[user1={YYY}]{CBIR}{CBIR}{Content Based Image Retrieval}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

\gls{CBIR}

\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=mystyle]

\end{document}
```